# can't turn off red-green 3D graphics on games for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, 3d-graphics

When we upgraded to Windows 7 suddenly all our games with 3D graphics displayed in red-green 3D and are pretty much un-playable without 3D glasses.

It's not a feature of the games themselves, it seems to be windows doing i to all the games, and it doesn't work very well on some of them.

How do i turn this feature off?

the video-card is a 
Asus EngTX280/ HTDP/ 1G Video Card

Comment: I don't think it's as much the fault of Windows as it is of the new drivers :)

Comment: what badp said. Definitely a video card driver issue. You have an nVdidia card probably? Check the 3D settings.

Comment: did the new drivers come when i upgraded windows?

Comment: and i don't think it's an nVdidia. We checked the settings with some help from a friend, but that didn't solve it.

Comment: @Bec - FYI, a quick search shows that the Asus EngTX280 is an Asus-made nVidia GTX 280. So you do have an nVidia card, and you'll probably find that you need to disable 3D Vision, as per the [answer](http://superuser.com/q/230675/#231300) by taspeotis.

Comment: Video cards are either going to be AMD or nVidia.  They make the actual GPUs that are in the cards.  The cards themselves are _manufactured_ by other companies, ASUS, Sapphire, etc.  Much like one could have an Intel or AMD processor in a Dell or Lenovo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Programs>>NVIDIA Corporation>>3D Vision>>Disable 3D Vision Discover

Comment: After doing this, I found that I still had to unplug the USB IR emitter, then re-connect it. After that, the glasses worked properly.

Answer (score -2):

I recently upgraded my drivers as well, an the same thing happened, 3D was automatically enabled for some reason, can be easily disabled in the NVidia settings, which fixes the problem :)